# Change Toast Font

Tags: android, toast, android-fonts

Currently, I'm trying to develop an app.
and I don't know how to change the Toast font. .

```
 final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(nova.this,"Hello", 500000).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(nova.this,"Exception:" +e, 500000);
            }
        }
    };
```

I want to change the text "Hello" with custom font I've tried with TypeFace.

and Then, I want to set a variable at the place "TextClicked" .. I've tried with a local variable .. but it doesn't work

any help with example source code will be really great for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the official documentation:

[Create your custom ToastView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView)

> If a simple text message isn't enough, you can create a customized layout for your toast notification. To create a custom layout, define a View layout, in XML or in your application code, and pass the root View object to the `setView(View)` method.

Following the link to the official Google Documentation will provide examples.

Answer (score 35):

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13231981

After refactoring a little:

```
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.yummyToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
    TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
    toastTV.setTextSize(30);
    toast.show();
```

This worked for me like a charm!

Comment: Best and nice ... .

Comment: This is risky.  If Google ever decides to change the layout so the first child isn't the TextView, you're going to get a a ClassCastException.

Comment: nice and neat ...!

Comment: @MartyMiller , is there any way to use `iterator` in this? I mean to get child at `int i` wheras i < totalChildLength then verifying if tha'ts textview or not

Comment: NOT WORKS in Android 11
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#text-toast-api-changes

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 11):

You can use a SpannableString to set the font:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ATaha.ttf");
SpannableString efr = new SpannableString("Toast font changed!");
efr.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(font), 0, efr.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
Toast.makeText(this, efr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

A custom Span class that has a specific Typeface set:

```
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    private Typeface mTypeface;
    public TypefaceSpan(Typeface typeface) {
        mTypeface = typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is most correct way to set Toast typeface and save system Toast styling.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the code on the Java page is bugged. Here is a link to a working function you can implement that gives you the text (I know, because I tested it), and with a little ingenuity, could be expanded to pass arguments for size, color, etc...

Toast Font size function [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/toastwithTextView.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin function:

```kt
fun makeLargeTextToast(text: CharSequence): Toast {
    return Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).also {
        val toastLayout = it.view as LinearLayout
        val toastTV = toastLayout.getChildAt(0) as TextView
        toastTV.textSize = 30f
    }
}
```

Use it as:

```
makeLargeTextToast("text message").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution in kotlin

**in CustomView or Fragment**

```
 fun persianToast(message: String): Toast {
    return Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).also {
        val view = it.view as LinearLayout
        val tv = view.getChildAt(0) as TextView
        val typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context?.assets, MyApplication.getFont(MyApplication.LIGHT_FONT))
        tv.typeface = typeFace
    }
 }
```

**MyApplication class :**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
companion object {
     const val NORMAL_FONT = 0
     const val BOLD_FONT = 1
     const val MEDIUM_FONT = 2
     const val LIGHT_FONT = 3
     const val ULTRA_LIGHT_FONT = 4

    @JvmStatic
    fun getFont(type: Int): String {
        return when (type) {
            LIGHT_FONT -> "font/fontLight.ttf"
            BOLD_FONT -> "font/fontBold.ttf"
            MEDIUM_FONT -> "font/fontMedium.ttf"
            ULTRA_LIGHT_FONT -> "font/fontUltraLight.ttf"
            else -> "font/fontNormal.ttf"
        }
    }
}
```

**used in fragment:**

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Toast(context)
        persianToast("javid sattar").show()
}
```

good luck!!