# How can we increase the font size in toast?

Tags: android, text, android-layout, font-size

Is there any way to increase the font size in toast without customizing?

I don't want to create a layout for increasing the text size.

Is there any way?

Thanks,

Niki

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I believe it is achieveable by this:

```
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(0);
    messageTextView.setTextSize(25);
```

Comment: This code crashes due to ClassCastException in some custom OS devices. 
java.lang.ClassCastException
android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Seems toast view is implemented with a RelativeLayout parent in this cases.
May be fixed by typecasting to ViewGroup instead of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 28):

**this is ...**

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.yummyToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//the default toast view group is a relativelayout
RelativeLayout toastLayout = (RelativeLayout) toast.getView();
TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
toastTV.setTextSize(30);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 24):

Here is how to do that with spans:

```
SpannableStringBuilder biggerText = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
biggerText.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.35f), 0, text.length(), 0);
Toast.makeText(context, biggerText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks, Perfect solution, May i expect?? So, This code working very well.

Comment: Thank's! Work fine

Answer (score 8):

You can't increase the font size without creating a [`CustomToastView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940465/change-toast-font) is a related question.

Comment: Thanks.. But even CustomToastView is not working in my Service.Where should we do the inflating part (onCreate or onStartCommand )? I tried in onCreate, but ended with error.

Answer (score 3):

Working from Ani's answer, another solution that allows you to set the text size to a dimension value would be something like:

```
public static void showToast(Context context, int resId) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, resId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
    TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
    toastTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
            context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.TEXT_SIZE));
    toast.show();
}
```

This lets you match the size you get your toasts to be the same size as specified in TextView and Button controls, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Nikolay [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981183/867786) this beautifully. Heuristically, it's pretty a safe bet that, if an Android API method takes a `CharSequence` instead of a `String` it means you can pass it `Spanned` (i.e. formatted) text.

If you don't want to want to build it by hand, and are more comfortable with HTML you can do this:

```
Toast.makeText(context, Html.fromHtml("<big>Big text.</big>"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

Or, if using a string resource, do this:

```
<string name="big_text"><big>Big text.</big></string>
```

And just use it like this:

```
Toast.makeText(context, R.string.big_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

The available markup is mostly documented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(0);
    messageTextView.setTextSize(30);
    toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(" ","The text you want here");

By keeping the first set of quotes empty, the second set will bold your text and make it easier to read.

Normally the line would be: .toast("Text you want here","The title of your toast popup");

By making your text as the Title, second set of quotes, and leaving the first quotes empty, your text is now easier to read.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to put the following code into your Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Put it above the `<Application>` element.

Comment: How is this even related to what the actual question is?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is an application-wide solution. Android might show larger toasts if it recognizes that the device has a large screen.