# Change font, font size of toast in iOS

Tags: ios, toast

I'm have used `Toast` before in Android. Is there a way to customize the font or font size of `Toast` on an `UIView` in iOS?

I am aware of the `makeToast` function, which seems to only have optional parameters for duration, position, image, and title. Or is there another messaging/notification system I should be using instead?

I already found this [answer for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274354/how-can-we-increase-the-font-size-of-toast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out toast is not native to obj-C like I originally thought? [Growl/toast style notifications library for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026273/growl-toast-style-notifications-library-for-ios/6811019#6811019)

It looks like the github project was already included in some of the legacy code I've been going through... but adding such custom features would not be an iOS issue like I thought, it'd be working on the github project.

Also, turns out that there's a native iOS library message system: [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Toast-like in iOS, but you can use something similar called popover. 
Popovers are from the documentations:

> is used to manage the presentation of content in a popover. You use
>   popovers to present information temporarily. The popover content is
>   layered on top of your existing content and the background is dimmed
>   automatically. The popover remains visible until the user taps outside
>   of the popover window or you explicitly dismiss it. Popover
>   controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to
>   create one on other devices results in an exception. However popovers
>   only available in iPads.

I would recommend the following control for you to use on iPhone and iPad, very easy to use and implement.
https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover