# How do you increase the Toast font size in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, font-size, toast

I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274354/how-can-we-increase-the-font-size-in-toast) on changing the Toast message size in Java, but how would this be done in Kotlin?

Comment: This is how to increase the Toast size with spannables: [How can we increase the font size in Toast?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981183/15535190)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent Kotlin code of the answer. Android Studio also transforms Java code into Kotlin automatically. Just copy and paste it.

Edit for activity :

```
 val toast = Toast.makeText(this,  "Text" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//the default toast view group is a relativelayout
val toastLayout = toast.getView() as ViewGroup
val toastTV =  toastLayout.getChildAt(0) as TextView
toastTV.setTextSize(30)
toast.show()
```

Comment: This caused the application to close, and said `java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.RelativeLayout`, referring to lines with `binding.fightButton.setOnClickListener { battle() }` and `val playerHitLayout = playerHitMonster.view as RelativeLayout`. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: I don't know about your context if it is activity or fragment, I just changed the code

Comment: Activity, not a fragment.

Comment: The error says "playerHitMonster.view" is null. Please check it if you declared it in correct way.

Comment: Now I get `android.widget.Toast cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout`. Why would I want to cast the Toast to the Relative Layout? Because this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I jusi converted the code to Kotlin the link you pointed, please try it with ViewGroup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231628/discussion-between-android-won-kenobi-and-eren-tufekci).