# How do you display a Toast using Kotlin on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

In different Kotlin examples for Android I see `toast("Some message...")` or `toastLong("Some long message")`. For example:

```
view.setOnClickListener { toast("Click") }
```

As I understand, it is an Extension Function for `Activity`.

How and where do you define this `toast()` function so that you are able to use it throughout the project?

Comment: You can use this simple kotlin friendly library. https://github.com/Sathawale27/KotlinToasts

Comment: I answered in this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63806312/10300202 I hope this help

Answer (score 167, accepted):

It can be an extension function for `Context`:

```
fun Context.toast(message: CharSequence) = 
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

You can place this anywhere in your project, where exactly is up to you. For example, you can define a file `mypackage.util.ContextExtensions.kt` and put it there as a top level function.

Whenever you have access to a `Context` instance, you can import this function and use it:

```
import mypackage.util.ContextExtensions.toast

fun myFun(context: Context) {
    context.toast("Hello world!")
}
```

Answer (score 113):

**This is one line solution in Kotlin:**

```
Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Its a toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Thx @Zeero0 , +1 for `this@MainActivity` .

Comment: I'm new to Kotlin, so pardon my ignorance, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Zeero0 Any reason you don't use requireContent() instead of this@MainActivity?

Comment: requireContext() is part of Fragment nor Activity

Answer (score 49):

It's actually a part of [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko), an extension for Kotlin. Syntax is as follows:

```
toast("Hi there!")
toast(R.string.message)
longToast("Wow, such a duration")
```

In your app-level `build.gradle`, add `implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.8.3"`

Add `import org.jetbrains.anko.toast` to your Activity.

Comment: It looks like this is not officially supported by Android (I couldn't find any reference to Anko in the Android developer's website). Why could it be it so? It looks very intriguing.

Comment: It was from a while back, before Kotlin was officially supported by Google. Anko appears to be an unfinished project. The goal was to replace XML for layouts entirely, but they didn't do so well at it. A lot of the benefits of Anko were also gradually built into Kotlin.

Comment: thanks, that was very helpful. I now wonder why isn't this extension already provided by the Kotlin extensions for Android. Or is it and I can't find how to add it? :thinking:

Answer (score 21):

Try this

In Activity

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(this@MainActiivty, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

In Fragment

```
Toast.makeText(activity, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use `anko` and want to create your own `Toast` extension. You can create inline(or without inline) extensions defined in a kotlin file(with no class) and with that you can access this function in any class.

```
inline fun Context.toast(message:String){
   Toast.makeText(this, message , duration).show()
}
```

Usage:

In Activity,

```
toast("Toast Message")
```

In Fragment,

```
context?.toast("Toast Message")
```

Answer (score 4):

A very simple extension.

Add this to a toast.kt file

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

inline fun Context.toast(message:()->String){
   Toast.makeText(this, message() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

inline fun Fragment.toast(message:()->String){
   Toast.makeText(this.context, message() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

then you'll have

```
toast {
   "Hello World"
}
```

in both fragment & activity.

Answer (score 3):

While using **Anko** with **Kotlin**, inside **fragment** use either:

```
 activity.toast("string message")
```

or

```
 context.toast("string message")
```

or

```
 view.holder.context.toast("string message")
```

Answer (score 3):

With this extension function for **Toasts**, you can call them in Activities as well as Fragments, you can pass **this** as `Context` for Activities or `getApplication()` for Fragments, also it's generated with `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` as default, so you don't need to worry to pass it as a parameter, but you can overwrite it as well if you need.

### Kotlin

```
fun Context.showToast(message: String, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT){
        Toast.makeText(context, message , duration).show()
    }
```

### Usage

```
showToast("John Doe")
```

if you want to override the duration.

```
showToast("John Doe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

Comment: why do you need to pass context again. you can absolutely use it as ```fun Context.toast(message: String, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT){
        Toast.makeText(this, message , duration).show()
    }``` then ```toast("John Doe")``` or ```toast("John Doe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)```

Comment: Nice contribution @IanElvister, I will update the answer

Answer (score 2):

I have found very easy way to Toast from given link
https://gist.github.com/felipearimateia/ee651e2694c21de2c812063980b89ca3. In this link Activity is used instead of Context. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Show a Toast **not from the UI Thread**, in a **Fragment**

```
activity?.runOnUiThread {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Image saved to the Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Android Toast for Kotlin**

> Activity

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "message...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

> Fragment

```
Toast.makeText(activity, "message...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply an extension function for `Context` (like other pointed out already).

You can find a lot of pre-defined android extension functions in [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko), which is probably what many of the tutorials use as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on @nhaarman's answer --> you probably want to add the `resourceId` support as well

```
fun Context.toast(resourceId: Int) = toast(getString(resourceId))
fun Context.toast(message: CharSequence) = 
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Download source code from here ([Custom Toast In Android Kotlin](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2018/04/custom-toast-in-android-kotlin.html) )

```
fun Toast.createToast(context: Context, message: String, gravity: Int, duration: Int, backgroucolor: String, imagebackgroud: Int) {
        val inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        /*first parameter is the layout you made
        second parameter is the root view in that xml
         */
        val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (context as Activity).findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container))

        layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_message).text = message
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroucolor))
        layout.findViewById(R.id.iv_image).iv_image.setImageResource(imagebackgroud)
        setGravity(gravity, 0, 100)
        setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        setView(layout);
        show()
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the way I use it **simply** creating an `Object`/`Class`

```
object UtilKotlin {
    fun showMessage(context: Context, message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

and calling the method

```
UtilKotlin.showMessage(activity, "Sets 0 !") // in activity trying this
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is extension of toast for activity or fragment**

```
fun showToast(context: Context,@StringRes string : Int, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT){
  Toast.makeText(context,string,duration).show()
 }


inline fun Context.toast(message:()->String){
 Toast.makeText(this, message() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}


inline fun Fragment.toast(message: () -> String, duration: () -> Int = { Toast.LENGTH_LONG }){
 Toast.makeText(this.context,message(),duration()).show()
}


inline fun AppCompatActivity.toast(message: () -> String, duration: () -> Int = { Toast.LENGTH_LONG }){
 Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext,message(),duration()).show()
}
```

**If you want simple toast just call first method both fragment and activity**

```
 showToast(yourContext,"your message")  or showToast(yourContext,"your message",1200L)
```

**Or**

```
toast {
 "Your message"
}
```

**Or**

```
toast({"your message"}) or toast({"your messge"},{your duration = 1200L})
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Toast with Background color Text size AND **NO XML** file inflated
Try the code without setting the Background color

```
    fun theTOAST(){

    val toast = Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Use View Person List",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    val view = toast.view
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    val text = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message) as TextView
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
    text.textSize = (18F)
    toast.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jetpack Compose use "context" from package "androidx.compose.runtime"

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Its a toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```