# Can't get app context (Unresolved reference)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get the context of the app to print a Toast message. The function that I use in Java is the following:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey! I'm working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But now, that I need to implement it in Kotlin, (language that I'm starting to learn) feel a bit lost. I have tried the following code (given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826004/kotlin-for-android-toast)) but it doesn't work as I am not able to get the context of the app.

```
Toast.makeText(this@CoreMainActivity, "Its toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Also, I am not able to get the context with `getApplicationContext()` as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context.html#getapplicationcontext).

I would be thankful to know how to call the `getApplicationContext()`, and to understand what exactly `this@CoreMainActivity` does (in the post `this@CoreMainActivity`). **Note that `coreMainActivity` is a Java file.**

Thanks!

Comment: *but doesn't work*, what do you mean by this? What problem it cause?

Comment: I get this message `Unresolved reference`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According your code

**If this works**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey! I'm working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Then it should also work**

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Its toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

**Update:** 
*According your implementation use `activity` instead of `applicationContext` that you get as parameter*

Comment: That's Java, I want Kotlin!!

Comment: @JuanCA, `Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Its toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`. It is in *Kotlin*

Comment: Can you add more details where you using this code and get `Unresolved reference`?

Comment: This would be inside the method `onOptionsItemSelected`. More information about the method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)). I know it's a very wide error, but I'm not very sure what else can I specify. Thanks for the help

Comment: It should not happen. Probably you missed something. Can you post your own implementation here so that I can investigate more?

Comment: Sure! Here goes: `  fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) =
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Its toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    when (item.itemId) {
      android.R.id.home -> {
        menuClickListener.onHomeMenuClicked()
        true
      }
      else -> false
    } `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205193/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-juan-ca).

Answer (score 2):

One of the following should work:

```
getContext()
getActivity()
this
CoreMainActivity.this
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
fun Context.toast(message: CharSequence) = 
Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

You can place this anywhere in your project, where exactly is up to you. For example, you can define a file `mypackage.util.ContextExtensions.kt` and put it there as a top level function

Whenever you have access to a Context instance, you can import this function and use it:

```
fun myFun(context: Context) {
    context.toast("Hello world!")
}
```

from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36826336/6430917

Answer (score 1):

Here are the various things we should know.

1.) Application Context - `getApplicationContext()` will use.

2.) Activity context - `coreMainActivity.this` will use (As you mentioned your java clas)

Now come on the Kotlin.

1.)Application Context -  `applicationContext` will use

2.)Activity context -  `this@CoreMainActivity` will use

As per the guideline avoid using application context and use activity context as per need.

NOTE: In your java class `this@CoreMainActivity` will not work.